# Post request with formData (mp4 file) and query params

Tags: python, post, python-requests, multipartform-data

```
def analyze_file_live(file=None,
                               enriched_output=False,
                               version=os.getenv("PRODUCT_VERSION"),
                               ):
    endpoint = "tracks/live/"
    url = os.getenv("API_URL") + endpoint
    access_token = get_access_token("DEV")
    headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}',
               "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" }

    track_directory = "_resources/_tracks/"
    track_name = random.choice(os.listdir(track_directory))
    file = {"file": (track_name, open(track_directory + track_name, 'rb'))}

    payload = {"file" : file,
               "version": version,
               "enriched_output": enriched_output }

    response = requests.post(url=url, params=payload, headers=headers)
    return response

result = analyze_file_live()
```

**result** = b'{"status":400,"timestamp":1619455751249,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found"}'

---

tried to remove file from the payload and pass it like so:

```
payload = {"version": version, "enriched_output": enriched_output }
response = requests.post(url=url, params=payload, headers=headers, files=file)
```

**error**: '{"status":400,"timestamp":1619457040237,"error":"Bad Request","message":"Failed to parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found"}'

---

Also tried using Request and Session from requests. refactored request:

```
request = Request("POST", url=url, params=payload, headers=headers, files=file).prepare()
s = Session()
response = s.send(request)
```

same error as sending the initial request

Answer (score 0):

not setting the 'Content-Type' worked.

```py
header = headers = {'Authorization': f'Bearer {access_token}' }
```